# Type error in python 3.6: Must be string not int

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that can find a definite integral but when i run it I get an error message that i can not figure out even after searching on several websites for the answer. This is my code:

```
    class Intagrals:
    def main(self):
        Coefficient = input("Coefficeient: ")
        Exponet = input("Exponet: ")
        X_start = input("X_Start: ")
        X_end = input("X_End: ")
        self.equation_parts(Coefficient,Exponet,X_start,X_end)

        '''
        For main to always run:    if __name__ == '__main__':
                                       main()
        '''
    def equation_parts(self,coefficient,exponet,x_start,x_end): #x_start and x_end are the beggining and end valuse to be set for x in the intagral
        exponet += 1 #adds one to exponet for equation to be solved correctly
        a_over_n_plus_1_x = coefficient/exponet #creates terms before x

    def math_of_intagral(self):
        solve_for_x = self.a_over_n_plus_1_x * self.x_end
        raise_to_power_end_x = solve_for_x ** self.exponet
        if self.x_start != 0:
            solve_for_start_x = self.a_over_n_plus_1_x * self.x_start
            raise_to_power_start_x = solve_for_start_x ** self.exponet
            return raise_to_power_end_x - raise_to_power_start_x
        else:
            return raise_to_power_end_x
intagrals = Intagrals()
```

Then it displays this error message after I enter some code:

```
> >>> intagrals.main()
Coefficeient: 1
Exponet: 2
X_Start: 0
X_End: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    intagrals.main()
  File "C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/intagrals.py", line 15, in main
    self.equation_parts(Coefficient,Exponet,X_start,X_end)
  File "C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/intagrals.py", line 22, in equation_parts
    exponet += 1 #adds one to exponet for equation to be solved correctly
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Can someone Please help?

Comment: `exponet = int(input("Exponet: "))`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function in python, it returns a string. To quote the docs (emphasis mine):

> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

As you see from the docs, the `input()` function converts the input to a string and returns it. Thus, you cannot perform operations like `+= 1` on it as it is a string.

To convert a string to an int, you need to use the `int()` function. Thus, the line of code will be:

```
Exponet = int(input("Exponet: "))
```

This will fix your issue as the `int()` function will cast the string to an int and then you should be able to perform operations like `+=` on them.

---

Side Note: `Exponet` is a wrong spelling, it is `Exponent` (note the extra `n`).

Comment: Now (after fixing some mistakes), it  gives this: AttributeError: 'Intagrals' object has no attribute 'a_over_n_plus_1_x'

Comment: @That_one_guy that is simply because you have not declared `a_over_n_plus_1_x` in the Class.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the `Exponet` from input and that is always a string, when you try to increment it with `exponet += 1` it gives that error.

You should modify your input to get an integer ant not a string, so change this line

```
Exponet = input("Exponet: ")
```

to this

```
Exponet = int(input("Exponet: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
something = input("Exponet: ")
```

python takes it always as string. So to convert it into integer using

```
something = int(input("Exponet: "))
```

Here when you input Exponet: 2, Python thinks it is a string but when you try to increment it fails to increment the integer value because of you input string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing `self.` before the `a_over...` variable that you set in the `equation_parts` method. Later, you're referring to this variables using `self.a_...` which causes the `AttributeError` to be thrown.